# Windows 10 Kiosk Mode - Edge with no sound issue

Tags: windows-10, audio, microsoft-edge, kiosk

I am starting Microsoft Edge in Kiosk mode via Assigned Access to display a simple webpage with sound. For some reason sound will not work until press the volume up or switch user and manually change the volume settings, then go back to kiosk mode. [Windows Kiosk Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3yii.png)

I have tried to change system memory value with no success.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c88c76f-6685-49df-891e-33b1f0cc57dc/assigned-access-audio-issue-windows-10-1809?forum=win10itprosetup

If I start the computer with an autologin, and then automatically start Chrome (instead of Edge) in kiosk mode, sound will not work either until I press volume up. The workaround I found for the Autologin solution is to active Windows Startup sound, wich does not work for Assigned Access Kiosk Mode.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found if I click on the webpage audio then comes into focus and works.